# Trouble Upgrading from Drupal9 to Drupal10

Tags: php, drupal

I'm fairly new to drupal and am having trouble upgrading from 9.5 to 10.

I have upgrade_status to 100% but when I try to upgrade to d10 through composer I get the following error.

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/drupal-extension ^4.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal-extension[v4.2.1, 4.2.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-alpha1 requires symfony/routing ~v6.2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v6.2.8, v6.2.12, v6.2.13, 6.2.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.3, ..., 10.0.x-dev] require symfony/routing ~v6.2.5 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v6.2.5, ..., 6.2.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-rc2, ..., 10.0.2] require symfony/routing ~v6.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v6.2.0-BETA1, ..., 6.2.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc1 requires symfony/routing ~v6.2.0-BETA2 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v6.2.0-BETA2, ..., 6.2.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/routing v6.2.13 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.1.0-rc1, ..., 10.1.x-dev] require symfony/event-dispatcher ~v6.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v6.3.0-BETA1, ..., 6.3.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ~v6.3.0-BETA1 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v6.3.0-BETA1, ..., 6.3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v6.3.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha6 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha6].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha5 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha5].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha4 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha4].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha3 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha3].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha2 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha2].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha1 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha1].
    - Only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta12, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.3, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.0.0-alpha6], drupal/seven[1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0]. drupal/core replaces drupal/seven and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - drupal/adminimal_theme[1.7.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require drupal/seven ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/seven[1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/adminimal_theme ^1.7 -> satisfiable by drupal/adminimal_theme[1.7.0, 1.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.0.0-beta2] require symfony/validator ~v6.1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/validator[v6.1.4, ..., 6.1.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha7 requires symfony/validator ~v6.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/validator[v6.1.1, ..., 6.1.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/validator v6.1.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].</code>
```

When I run composer prohibits drupal/core-recommended 10 I get the following

```
drupal/core-recommended   9.5.10      requires         drupal/core (9.5.10)                                    
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/console (^6.2)                                  
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/console (but v4.4.49 is installed)              
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/dependency-injection (^6.2)                     
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/dependency-injection (but v4.4.49 is installed) 
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/event-dispatcher (^6.2)                         
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/event-dispatcher (but v4.4.44 is installed)     
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/http-foundation (^6.2)                          
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/http-foundation (but v4.4.49 is installed)      
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/http-kernel (^6.2)                              
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/http-kernel (but v4.4.50 is installed)          
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/mime (^6.2)                                     
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/mime (but v5.4.13 is installed)                 
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/routing (^6.2)                                  
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/routing (but v4.4.44 is installed)              
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/serializer (^6.2)                               
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/serializer (but v4.4.47 is installed)           
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/validator (^6.2)                                
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/validator (but v4.4.48 is installed)            
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/process (^6.2)                                  
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/process (but v4.4.44 is installed)              
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         symfony/yaml (^6.2)                                     
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require symfony/yaml (but v4.4.45 is installed)                 
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         twig/twig (^3.4.3)                                      
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require twig/twig (but v2.15.5 is installed)                    
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.5)                                
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require guzzlehttp/guzzle (but 6.5.8 is installed)              
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         guzzlehttp/psr7 (^2.4)                                  
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require guzzlehttp/psr7 (but 1.9.1 is installed)                
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         asm89/stack-cors (^2.1)                                 
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require asm89/stack-cors (but 1.3.0 is installed)               
drupal/core               10.0.0      requires         psr/log (^3.0)                                          
website/intranet-project dev-develop does not require psr/log (but 1.1.4 is installed)
```

The following is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "website/intranet-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "bluecadet/bluecadet_utilities": "^4.0",
        "composer/installers": "^1.12",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/address": "^1.12",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.7",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^2.0",
        "drupal/bigmenu": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/chosen": "^4.0",
        "drupal/components": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.4",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.9",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10",
        "drupal/crop": "^2.3",
        "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.1",
        "drupal/drupal-extension": "^4.2",
        "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.2",
        "drupal/elasticsearch_connector": "^7.0@alpha",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.9",
        "drupal/entity_clone": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.4",
        "drupal/entity_field_condition": "^1.4",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.10",
        "drupal/entity_usage": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/environment_indicator": "^4.0",
        "drupal/externalauth": "^2.0",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.4",
        "drupal/file_delete": "^2.0",
        "drupal/file_mdm": "^2.6",
        "drupal/focal_point": "^2.0",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^4.0",
        "drupal/google_tag": "^2.0",
        "drupal/gtm": "^1.8",
        "drupal/health_check_url": "3.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/iframe": "^2.23",
        "drupal/image_effects": "^3.4",
        "drupal/improved_multi_select": "^1.8",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^2.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_draggable": "^2.0",
        "drupal/linkit": "^6.0",
        "drupal/login_redirect_per_role": "^1.9",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/media_entity_browser": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/media_entity_file_replace": "^1.1",
        "drupal/memcache": "^2.5",
        "drupal/menu_block": "^1.10",
        "drupal/menu_breadcrumb": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.3",
        "drupal/metatag": "^2.0",
        "drupal/name": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/nodeaccess": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/override_node_options": "^2.7",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.16",
        "drupal/paragraphs_access": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/private_files_download_permission": "^3.1",
        "drupal/queue_ui": "^3.1",
        "drupal/r4032login": "^2.2",
        "drupal/rabbit_hole": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/rac": "^2.0",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.2",
        "drupal/recreate_block_content": "^3.0",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.9",
        "drupal/redis": "^1.7",
        "drupal/remote_stream_wrapper": "^2.0",
        "drupal/restui": "^1.21",
        "drupal/save_edit": "^1.6",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^2.0",
        "drupal/scheduler_content_moderation_integration": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.29",
        "drupal/search_api_exclude_entity": "^2.0",
        "drupal/simple_block": "^1.4",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^4.1",
        "drupal/simplesamlphp_auth": "4.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/stage_file_proxy": "^2.1",
        "drupal/time_field": "^2.1",
        "drupal/token": "^1.12",
        "drupal/token_filter": "^2.0",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/unpublished_paragraphs": "^1.3",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^4.0",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.5",
        "drupal/view_unpublished": "^1.1",
        "drupal/views_ajax_history": "^1.7",
        "drupal/viewsreference": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.2@beta",
        "drupal/webform_config_ignore": "^1.3",
        "drupal/webform_views": "^5.2",
        "drush/drush": "*",
        "kint-php/kint": "^5.0",
        "laminas/laminas-text": "^2.10",
        "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "^1.19"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build-assets": [
            "composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev"
        ],
        "lint": "find web/modules/custom web/themes/custom -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \\;",
        "install-codestandards": [
            "Dealerdirect\\Composer\\Plugin\\Installers\\PHPCodeSniffer\\Plugin::run"
        ],
        "code-sniff": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set ignore_errors_on_exit 1",
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set ignore_warnings_on_exit 1",
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs -s --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,scss,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,dist --exclude=Drupal.InfoFiles.AutoAddedKeys --colors ./web/modules/custom",
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs -s --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,scss,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,fractal,dist --exclude=Drupal.InfoFiles.AutoAddedKeys --colors ./web/themes/custom",
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs -s --standard=DrupalPractice --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,scss,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,dist --exclude=Drupal.InfoFiles.AutoAddedKeys --colors ./web/modules/custom",
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs -s --standard=DrupalPractice --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,scss,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,fractal,dist --exclude=Drupal.InfoFiles.AutoAddedKeys --colors ./web/themes/custom"
        ],
        "unit-test": "echo 'No unit test step defined.'",
        "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
        "prepare-for-pantheon": "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareForPantheon",
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@drupal-scaffold",
            "@install-codestandards",
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles",
            "ln -f -s `pwd`/private/simplesamlphp/config/* ./vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/config/",
            "ln -f -s `pwd`/private/simplesamlphp/metadata/* ./vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/metadata/",
            "cd web && patch -p1 <../patches/htaccess.patch",
            "cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush -y pm:enable health_check_url",
            "cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush -y pm:enable simplesamlphp_auth",
            "cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush -y pm:enable memcache",
            "cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush cr"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": ["custom-drupal-module"],
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/modules/bluecadet/{$name}": ["type:custom-drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "build-env": {
            "install-cms": [
                "drush site-install standard --account-mail={account-mail} --account-name={account-name} --account-pass={account-pass} --site-mail={site-mail} --site-name={site-name} --yes",
                "drush pm-enable config_direct_save simple_block --yes",
                "drush pm-uninstall block_content --yes"
            ],
            "export-configuration": "drush config-export --yes"
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
                "[project-root]/.editorconfig": false,
                "[web-root]/.csslintrc": false,
                "[web-root]/.eslintignore": false,
                "[web-root]/.eslintrc.json": false,
                "[web-root]/.web.config": false
            }
        },
        "patches": {
            "d10-compatibility-patch":{
                "d10-compatibility": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-06-28/0001-D10-comaptible-issues.patch"
            }
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "simplesamlphp/composer-module-installer": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "drupal/core-dev": "^10",
            "drupal/devel": "^5.1",
            "drupal/devel_php": "^1.5",
            "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.10"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only 2 months into my first drupal job and I am tasked with upgrading to D10 but I am really unsure where to go from here.
If anyone could give me a push in the right direction it would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.3 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.3 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.3 --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Try to run this composer command which is the latest Drupal 10 release version. And fix them one by one if any composer error occurs.

Comment: If you encounter any error after you can post here or comment.  I can help to resolve it